# AngularJSでローカルにあるjsonを読み込みたい。

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

AngularJSで以下の様なローカルに存在するファイルを読み込みたいです。

color.json

```html
[
   {
    "color": "'rgba(255, 23, 68, 0.2)'"
   },
   {
    "color": "'rgba(245, 0, 87, 0.2)'"
   },
   {
    "color": "'rgba(213, 0, 249, 0.2)'"
   }
]
```

`var colors = $resource('./color.json').query();`
で読み込んで

`console.log(colors)`で表示しようとしても`undefined`になってしまいます。
なぜでしょうか

Comment: HTMLファイルを直に開いているとブラウザによってはアクセス権限のポリシーに引っかかりますが、ウェブサーバーは通していますか？
http://eien.seesaa.net/article/302127165.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-resource.js
queryの結果がundefineになる事はありません。

queryの戻り値を直ぐjsonオブジェクトとして使用できる訳ではありません。
urlに非同期でアクセスし、戻ってきて始めてjsonオブジェクトとして使用できます。

```
var colors = $resource('./color.json').query();
colors.$promise.then(function(){
    // この関数が呼ばれるまでjsopnオブジェクトとして使用不可能
});
```

queryに関数を渡す事でもっと簡単に書けます

```
var colors = $resource('./color.json').query((function(){
    // この関数が呼ばれるまでjsopnオブジェクトとして使用不可能
});
```